# Brita water on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, water, borer-separating

Is there a Halacha issue regarding a brita water cup on Shabbat (namely, borer)? Would this considered be separating or no?

Comment: There is a Mishna Brura that discusses and permits this - 319 if I recall right - will aim to look for the source later

Comment: [OC 319:10 MB 34](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.319.10?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.319.35&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en), based on this poskim allow to filter for the one who drinks unfiltered water as well. For the one particular to drink *only* filtered water, R Nissem Karelitz permits, R Eliashiv and R Wosner forbid